# Pytorch Transform to predict numeric sequences

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

I'm interested in training a Pytorch Transformer model to predict numeric sequences.  I'm looking for a practical example from which to learn.  Can anyone point me to one?

Something like,

I train it on a sequence of numbers range(1,100).
I give it [22, 23] and it will produce [24, 25, 26, ..]
Later, the samples would be vectors.

I'm new to PyTorch and Transformers, but this can't be hard, right?

Comment: [https://github.com/ZouJiu1/numpy_transformer](https://github.com/ZouJiu1/numpy_transformer), this code can generate alphabet, using transformer